# How to create / combine / concatenate boost::format from multiple boost::format

Tags: c++, boost, format, boost-format

This is given:

```
boost::format greeting("%s (Greeting)");
boost::format name("%s (Name)");
```

'greetingwithname' should combine and reuses 'greeting' and 'name' so that it is equivalent to this:

```
boost::format greetingwithname("%s (Greeting) %s (Name)");
// looking for solution to like boost::format greetingwithname = greeting + name;
```

**How do I / What is the best way to create a boost::format object from multiple boost:format objects?**

Comment: It's not an option and AFAICT it's not implementable from the  public interface. Cheap solution: concatenate the format strings instead of the formatter objects.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, if there is no easy solution I will work with the std::string and apply the final result to the formatter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to concatenate the `boost::format` objects, but as @sehe commented you can concatenate the format strings instead and create a format object from that.